# World of 2-dimensional beings

Tags: spacetime-dimensions, thought-experiment, perception

In a world of two-dimensional beings, How would a two-dimensional (A) being view another two-dimensional (B) being as? Would they always perceive each other as a straight line?

Comment: [Flatland -A Romance in Many Dimensions](https://ia802708.us.archive.org/9/items/flatlandromanceo00abbouoft/flatlandromanceo00abbouoft.pdf) and many subsequent scientific publications including and annotated version by Ian Stewart.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not really about physics.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they are all straight lines! In order for 2D beings to distinguish between each other, one way is to rotate themselves, and a 2D being will recognize another by how the line one represents shortens and lengthens as one rotates.

This is famously illustrated and explained lucidly by Carl Sagan.

Comment: So, can we use this as an analogy for three-dimensional beings?